# Is it safe to store personal plaintext passwords in a private mysql database?

Tags: mysql, passwords, save, private, plaintext

I am wondering if it's safe to store your own passwords in a mysql database? What I want to do is just make a table with information such as the website, my username/email and my passwords. The mysql database won't have a domain attached to it (apart from the standard one you get with every webhosting package). I won't advertise or tell anyone the domain or even about the existence of my database and will manually fill in everything in phpmyadmin. My question is that since it's still in plaintext, is it considered safe? I won't make a website-based crud system and will purely do everything straight on phpmyadmin.

Thank you

Comment: You should never store plaintext passwords, anywhere, under any circumstances.

Comment: Is this proposed database stored on a computer that is connected to a network?  If so, no!

Comment: What if someone steals your PhpMyAdmin password? Or compromises your computer or webhost?

Comment: Yes, on a well known webhost. Edit: Well yes what if someone walks into my house and takes my notebook with passwords? If someone compromises my computer or gets through my 2-step on my google account I will lose everything anyways right now.

Comment: You're asking for opinions, which are explicitly off-topic.

Comment: I am asking for knowledge about how often mysql databases from webhosts are compromised or if someone else has experience in this. I know for example that 000webost got leaked.

Comment: Dude. https://1password.com/ or https://lastpass.com/. That you're proposing to admin this via phpMyAdmin is a horrible, horrible sign - it's frequently compromised.

Answer (score 0):

Storing passwords plaintext in a database on a shared hosting is nearly as safe as sending your passwords on a postcard to your neighbour, so he can safely store them in the fridge.

1. If you do not have an encrypted HTTPS/SSL connection to your website, it is relatively easy to eavesdrop the communication, thus the analogy with the postcard.
2. You have to trust your neighbour, that he does not glimpse at the postcard when he gets his breakfast. The same goes for the employees of your provider, when they have to do a backup or the like.
3. If your neighbour has visitors, they could also read the passwords, this is what an attacker can do e.g. with SQL-injection.
4. Then there is the problem with backups and discarded servers, if not done carefully, your passwords are copied to many locations (cloud), and it can become impossible to remove them everywhere. So it is only nearly as safe as the postcard.

Conclusion: Use a tool like [keepass](http://keepass.info/), it can store the passwords encrypted on an FTP server, so you can share the same repository with your PC, phone, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear *why* you want to do this - but there are many better solutions for storing your credentials.

To answer the question:

- Every website is subject to relentless, untargeted, scripted attacks, 24/7/365.
- Popular web hosts are subject to targeted attacks, looking for vulnerabilities in common tools like PHPMyAdmin. Again, relentless, scripted, 24/7.
- The scripts specifically search out high-value information like usernames and passwords, along with other financial and personally-identifiable information. This information is then routinely sold on.

So, by doing this, you will put the safety your credentials (and thus possibly your financial wellbeing) in the hands of at least two organizations - the developers of [PHPMyAdmin](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-784/Phpmyadmin.html), and your webhosting provider. If either of them fail, your details will be sold to the highest bidder within minutes.

It's not really a risk I'd want to take...